# Vee-validate 3.0 configure defaultMessage with vue-18n and TS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vue-i18n

I'm trying to define the [vee-validate configure object](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/configuration.html),`defaultMessage` in TS. I have seen this code in the [examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-vuei18n-integration-9vs4l?from-embed), `vee-validate.js` file:

```js
configure({
  defaultMessage: (field, values) => {
    // override the field name.
    values._field_ = i18n.t(`fields.${field}`);

    return i18n.t(`validation.${values._rule_}`, values);
  }
});
```

I try to convert in TS

```js
const dm: string | ValidationMessageGenerator | undefined =
    (field: string, values: Record<string, any>) => {
        values._field_ = i18n.t(`fields.${field}`);
        return (i18n.t(`validation.${values._rule_}`, values)) as string | ValidationMessageGenerator;
    };
configure({
    defaultMessage: dm,
});
```

But, I try to type, I always have this Errors:

`El tipo '(field: string, values: Record<string, any>) => ValidationMessageTemplate' no se puede asignar al tipo 'string | ValidationMessageGenerator | undefined'.
  El tipo '(field: string, values: Record<string, any>) => ValidationMessageTemplate' no se puede asignar al tipo 'ValidationMessageGenerator'.
    Los tipos de parámetros 'values' y 'params' no son compatibles.
      El tipo 'Record<string, any> | undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Record<string, any>'.
        El tipo 'undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Record<string, any>'.ts(2322)`

The only configuration which works for me is to set the flags `//@ts-ignore` and use the javascript code, works, but I would like to type it and remove the flag

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have all this casting, you should read the typings carefully as there as some subtle differences, this should work:

```js
const dm = (field: string, values: Record<string, any> = {}) => {
  values._field_ = i18n.t(`fields.${field}`);

  return (i18n.t(`validation.${values._rule_}`, values));
};

configure({
  defaultMessage: dm,
});
```

You were missing that `values` is optional and is not actually required by the `ValidationMessageGenerator` type, because not all rules have parameters.